# Center the label in a ComboBox element with a custom ComboBoxStyle

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am using `QtQuick.Controls 1.0` and `QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0` and I can't find a way to properly align the label of the `ComboBox` vertically and on the right.

This is my current code

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0


ComboBox {
  id: comboCategories
  width: 230
  height: 30

  style: ComboBoxStyle {
    background: Rectangle {
      id: rectCategory
      width: comboCategories.width
      height: comboCategories.height
      color: "white"
    }

    label: Text {
      anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
      anchors.right: background.right
      font.pointSize: 12
      color: "#808080"
      text: control.currentText
    }
  }
}
```

But the label stays in the top left of my element and does not seem to be affected by the anchors. I also tried to replace `parent` with `control` or `background` with no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know the reasoning behind this but if I wrap my `Text` element in an `Item` then I can properly

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0

ComboBox {
  id: comboCategories
  width: 230
  height: 30

  style: ComboBoxStyle {
    background: Rectangle {
      id: rectCategory
      width: comboCategories.width
      height: comboCategories.height
      color: "white"
    }

    label: Item {
      anchors.fill: parent
      Text {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 5
        font.pointSize: 12
        color: "#808080"
        text: control.currentText
      }
  }
}
```